# Can members pay renew fees early?

Tags: civimember, auto-renew

Can members pay their dues early? Basically before the system has them as expired.

Answer (score 4):

If they renew early, it should just extend their membership. (e.g. if it is an annual membership and they have 2 months left when they renew, they should have 14 months on their membership afterwards).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using memberships with fixed dates (e.g. calendar year memberships), then there is a setting "Fixed Period Rollover Day" that will control at which point a membership for the following period can be added.